# What does commandtype=&H0004 mean?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

While going through ADO.NET code i came across the term called command type. Even though i know the basic meaning of the command type, i want to know What does command type=&H0004 mean? and what would the output of this would be?

I have already tried it googling it but couldn't get the  description about this.Please help me on this as am struck at this.

Comment: It seems that's [ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/editmodeenum?view=sql-server-2017) not ADO.NET. But you should show the code anyway. In VB.NET this compiles: `Const adEditDelete = &H0004` and is an integer constant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean System.Data.CommandType? In that case &H0004 means StoredProcedure (see following snippet from metadata) ...

```
public enum CommandType
{
    Text = 1,
    StoredProcedure = 4,
    TableDirect = 512
}
```